# iOS UITableViewWrapperView not present in iOS 11 with Xcode9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

`UITableViewWrapperView` is not present in iOS11, When I build my App using Xcode9.

I am setting background view for my `UITableView` by using `insertSubview` method of `UIView`, that code is working fine with all iOS versions when I compiled my code using Xcode8 but when I build same code using Xcode9 then content is invisible(on iOS 11) because background layer coming over cells.

Below is debug results -

1. **Xcode9 and iOS 11** -

   A. Before Adding background

   > ```
   > ▿ 2 elements
   >   - 1 : <UIImageView: 0x7fe7f5f045c0; frame = (3 710.667; 408 2.33333); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000223f80>>
   >   - 2 : <UIImageView: 0x7fe7f5f01e30; frame = (408.667 3; 2.33333 385); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled> = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000226720>>
   > ```

   B. After Adding background

   > ```
   > ▿ 3 elements
   >   - 0 : <UIView: 0x7fe7f5e09840; frame = (0 0; 414 736); layer = <CALayer: 0x60400003d780>>
   >   - 1 : <UIImageView: 0x7fe7f5f045c0; frame = (3 710.667; 408 2.33333); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000223f80>>
   >   - 2 : <UIImageView: 0x7fe7f5f01e30; frame = (408.667 3; 2.33333 385); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled> = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000226720>>
   > ```
2. **Xcode8 and iOS 11 - UITableViewWrapperView is present** -

   A. Before Adding background

   > ```
   > 3 elements
   >   - 0 : <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7ffdbe81cc00; frame = (0 0; 375 647); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x608000244a10>; layer => <CALayer: 0x608000028cc0>;contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375,> 647}>
   >   - 1 : <UIImageView: 0x7ffdbe406af0; frame = (3 641.5; 369 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO;layer = <CALayer: 0x608000028fe0>>
   >   - 2 : <UIImageView: 0x7ffdbe407320; frame = (369.5 637; 2.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO;> layer = <CALayer: 0x608000029140>>
   > ```

   B. After Adding background

   > ```
   > 4 elements
   >   - 0 : <UIView: 0x7ffdbe505cc0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000002a460>>
   >   - 1 : <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7ffdbe81cc00; frame = (0 0; 375 647); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x608000244a10>; layer =<CALayer: 0x608000028cc0>; contentOffset: {0, 0};contentSize: {375,647}>
   >   - 2 : <UIImageView: 0x7ffdbe40b0f0; frame = (3 641.5; 369 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO;layer = <CALayer: 0x608000029e00>>
   >   - 3 : <UIImageView: 0x7ffdbe40b550; frame = (369.5 637; 2.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO;layer = <CALayer: 0x608000029f00>>
   > ```

Method to set background -

```
   private func setTableViewBackground() {

        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.frame = view.frame

        let maskPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: backgroundView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: ([.topLeft, .topRight]), cornerRadii: CGSize(width:20, height:20))

        let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = backgroundView.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        backgroundView.layer.mask = maskLayer
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        myCustomTableView.insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 0)
    }
```

**Build using Xcode8 on iOS11**

[image: Xcode8_iOS11]

**Build using Xcode9 on iOS11**

[image]

I found [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82320) link, which confirms that `UITableViewWrapperView` is removed from iOS11, but just when we compile code using Xcode9?

Answer (score 1):

That's why I don't like to use undocumented features. Apple guys change them as they want without notifications.
My suggestion for your case is to put table view on a red substrate in IB and apply your code.

NB. Don't forget to set `clipsToBounds` property to `true`.

The function will be even shorter:

```
private func setTableViewBackground() {
    let backgroundView = self.tableViewSubstrate!
    let maskPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: backgroundView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: ([.topLeft, .topRight]), cornerRadii: CGSize(width:20, height:20))
    let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    backgroundView.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

You can find sample project here: https://github.com/AlexeyGolovenkov/TableWithRoundCorners

Comment: Than you for your reply, ActuallyI am not looking for alternate solutions, instead I am trying to figure out why it behaving different.

Answer (score 0):

Check your target build settings. You might be building to latest OS and switching from XCode 8 to 9 moved your compile target OS from 10 to 11. This may also be a differentiation between any debug versus release builds. You can change your target in XCode 9 to iOS 10 and it will recompile with the issues fixed, but you risk deprecation problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my actually concern is why background color is showing on top, either I placed it on zero index.

Comment: Apple specifically warns you in iOS 11 to not mess with anything inside UITableViews. The effect here is that your code is drawing over the view instead of inside the view hierarchy stack. They consider your attempts a bad coding practice and have written code to prevent you from causing bugs other devs would have to fix if someone wrote code like this. It's not hard to watch the view stack and observe someone's attempt to change it.

Comment: But if you will check, Cells are also in same hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, but they're part of the intended code. You're trying to inject views into the parent hierarchy. UITableViewCells are designed to be views, but behind the scene they turn into a helper view to lighten the memory footprint and work faster on mobile devices.  Originally on Mac OS, it was a huge memory and speed hit to have a large amount of separate views. Apple created the concept of NSCells, but they were hard to use as easily as a view and left developers making inefficient apps with heavy view usage. In iOS, they created special helper views like UITableViewCell with better memory usage.

Comment: Sorry Derek, I didn't understand why there is a difference here if I inject view in hierarchy. Is there any Apple document related to that?

Comment: Apple added new swipe actions to UITableViews in iOS 11. Your code could potentially break those actions. I guess that is the simplest explanation.

Comment: Furthermore, Apple is protecting the UIResponder chain. Placing a view in that chain can unintentionally intercept UI events.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to replace `myCustomTableView.insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 0)` with

> myCustomTableView.backgroundView = backgroundView

It's working fine for me.

Comment: Than you for your reply, ActuallyI am not looking for alternate solutions, instead I am trying to figure out why it behaving different.

Answer (score -1):

bro i think this below line of code may useful to you.

old code :

```
 private func setTableViewBackground() {

    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.frame = view.frame

    let maskPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: backgroundView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: ([.topLeft, .topRight]), cornerRadii: CGSize(width:20, height:20))

    let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = backgroundView.bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    backgroundView.layer.mask = maskLayer
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    myCustomTableView.insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 0)
}
```

Replace with below code :

```
 private func setTableViewBackground() {

    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.frame = view.frame

    let maskPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: backgroundView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: ([.topLeft, .topRight]), cornerRadii: CGSize(width:20, height:20))

    let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = backgroundView.bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    backgroundView.layer.mask = maskLayer
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    // myCustomTableView.insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 0)

    myCustomTableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```